# Pip packages installed inside the env and globally

Tags: python, pip, package, environment-variables, virtualenv

I have a Django project. I created an env and I go inside the env. All the packages installed through pip are installed globally AND inside the env.

How can avoid installing them globally when I'm inside the env? (They're installed inside the folder: site-packages, inside python3.9).

"which pip" command gave me the same path if I'm inside the env or not: /opt/homebrew/bin/pip

Thank you so much.

Comment: "*I created an env…*" What kind of `env`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, activate the virtualenv by `source {your_virtual_enviroment_name}/bin/activate`

Second, install the libraries by `pip install {library_name}` or  `pip install -r requirements.txt` if you have one.

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt` <- you've forgotten **-r**.